# Insert and update in the same transaction

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have heard you can not insert a row first and immediately update it in next statement in the same transaction in SQL Server? But I have been doing that (SQL Server 2005) and my results show its been done. Am I missing something or doing something stupid here? Please enlighten. Thanks.

Comment: could you provide the code you used?

Comment: also do you have a source to the information that this cannot be done? - there is probably just a misunderstanding. Its certainly not something I've had problems with.

Comment: You may be thinking of [issues around upserts](http://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx) prior to SQL Server 2008's introduction of the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience insert and update in the same query may result in locked queries if the amount of inserts are relatively high. I'd consider creating triggers on insert and modify values before inserting them. Not sure how relevant this approach would be in your case. But having said that, it is definitely possible to do insert and update in the same query.

Comment: Yes you are probably right! Moreover I could use the Output clause to avoid putting a trigger. But I just wanted to make sure if this was possible (insertion and update in the same transaction).  Also, if I need the value of identity of the newly inserted row to do further processing, I could better use - SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of taking MAX(id)... I hope this is a right approach too. Thanks guys for replying. I will yet not close the question, for I may get some interesting remarks/comments.

Comment: DECLARE @LastRecordID int
Perform Insert

SET @LastRecordID=@@IDENTITY

UPDATE table SET Column=Value WHERE ID=@LastRecordID